# findById returning empty in Junit Test case

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I am testing update Employee method using junit. Here is junit code looks like

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class EmployeeServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    EmployeeService service;
    
    @Mock
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;
    
    @Mock
    Employee emp;
    
    @Before
    public void SetupContext() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        emp = new Employee(1,"Ankush",4000,"Mumbai");
    }
    
    
    @Test
    public void updateEmployee() throws, Exception {
        when(empRepo.save(emp)).thenReturn(emp);
        EmployeeDTO empDTO=new EmployeeDTO(emp.getId(),"Ankush",4000,"Chennai");
        EmployeeDTO updatedEmp = service.updateEmployee(empDTO);
        assertThat(updatedEmp.getCity().equals("Chennai"));
    }
   }
```

Inside `updateEmployee` service method i am having one check like

```
public EmployeeDTO updateEmployee(EmployeeDTO empDTO){
     Optional<Employee> existingemp = empRepo.findById(empDTO.getId());
     if(existingemp.present()){
         //  converting DTO to entity
          empRepo.save(entity); 
      }else{
         throw new EmployeeServiceException("Employee Not Found to update");
      }
    return convertEntityToDto(entity);
 }
```

Why `existingemp` is always empty i had already saved the object `when(empRepo.save(emp)).thenReturn(emp);` where `emp` have the id `1` only.

Comment: have you mock `findById()` method?

Comment: @lucumt no , how do i can do this ?

Comment: see deadpool's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mock the `save` method since that method is not called in `updateEmployee` method. You should only mock the dependent methods inside the  actual method for which we are writing test cases, so in this case you need to mock `findById`

```
when(empRepo.findById(emp.getId()))).thenReturn(Optional.of(emp));
EmployeeDTO empDTO=new EmployeeDTO(emp.getId(),"Ankush",4000,"Chennai");
EmployeeDTO updatedEmp = service.updateEmployee(empDTO);
assertThat(updatedEmp.getCity().equals("Chennai"));
```

Comment: getting `No value present `

Comment: No value present  at line 13 `when(empRepo.findById(emp.getId()).get()).thenReturn(emp);`

Comment: Findbyid returns optional of value @UnknownGuy

Comment: why is `updatedEmp` i am getting as `null` at this line `empRepo.save(entity); ` however `entity` does have every fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public EmployeeDTO updateEmployee(EmployeeDTO empDTO){
    Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = 
    empRepo.findById(empDTO.getId());
    Employee existingEmployee=null;

    if(optionalEmployee.isPresent()){
        existingEmployee=optionalEmployee.get();
    }else{
        throw new EmployeeServiceException("Employee Not Found to update");
    }
    // Use setter to update the fields
    
    return convertEntityToDto(entity);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about your answer